# Attach a xml layout file in flutter page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible any way to attach Android xml layout file in flutter using method channel and represent in flutter dart page

Answer (score 0):

Platform views allow you to embed native views in Flutter app.
It can be done in 2 ways.

1. Virtual displays
2. Hybrid composition.

[Official guide to implement platform view](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views)

Comment: i can also setup This code and its working bt i have layout.xml file and i have to represent on Flutter Side.